# How to make utf8_encode display Normal PHP code?

Tags: php, utf-8

I am a Beginner Programmer.
I want to ask something..

How to make `utf8_encode` display Normal **PHP** code?

I mean like this :

```
<?php
$string = utf8_encode("\x65\x63\x68\x6F\x20\x27\x68\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x20\x77\x6F\x72\x6C\x64\x27\x3B"); echo $string;
?>
```

If you look at the code, then the result is like this:

```
echo 'hello world';
```

not like:

```
hello world
```

I want to show `hello world` not `echo 'hello world';`

how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Each of the `\x` codes are characters. So, if you want *just* `hello world`, you will need just the subset:

```
\x65 | e
\x63 | c
\x68 | h
\x6F | o
\x20 | 
\x27 | '
\x68 | h
\x65 | e
\x6C | l
\x6C | l
\x6F | o
\x20 | 
\x77 | w
\x6F | o
\x72 | r
\x6C | l
\x64 | d
\x27 | '
\x3B | ;
```

So try:

```php
<?php
$string = utf8_encode("\x68\x65\x6C\x6C\x6F\x20\x77\x6F\x72\x6C\x64");
echo $string;
?>
```